# Sexual reproduction in organisms with 1 parent

Tags: human-biology, genetics, sexual-reproduction

An organism that carries out sexual reproduction with itself,  for example a flower with both the anther and stigma,  does it actually contain 2 sets of genes in order to produce genetically dissimilar organisms or do it just leave the offspring to become genetically dissimilar through random crossing over during miosis?

Answer (score 2):

Your second piece is correct: dissimilarity is produced through meiosis.

from [The evolution of meiotic sex and its alternatives](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5031655/)

> Strikingly, almost all forms of uniparental reproduction do maintain
>   meiosis, but abandon just outcrossing. Hence, the paradox of sex in
>   eukaryotes must focus on the purpose of meiosis.

Comment: What do you mean by abondoning outcrossing?